# Challenge - Post questions about an aspect of an art we've always been curious about but have never gotten around to asking about

Tags: discussion

As per https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52160896#52160896, we're trying to get this Stack Exchange more active by getting some of our frequent posters posting more frequently. In this case, we're exploring those martial arts questions that you've long harbored but never really gotten around to asking.

> Maybe a meta contest where we have to ask questions about an aspect of an art we've always been curious about but never figure to ask?

There's been some discussion of maybe awarding bounties, although part of the problem is that one awards bounties on answers, not questions.

Comment: [Shuriken in Aikido](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/9506/82) because why not?

Comment: At least for me, this is something that I have always wondered: https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9730/why-isnt-striking-part-of-brazilian-jiu-jitsu/9731#9731

Answer (score 2):

I've opened with [What is the purpose of the "ox fist", a strike with the top of the wrist?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9497/) about a bent wrist strike I saw many years ago. And, as chance would have it, I found an answer although some details are still not present

Comment: As an FYI, (And I will post this on the question too), some styles call that a "bow hand strike".

Answer (score 2):

Question about naming of Japanese martial arts with other Eastern influences: [Does "do" v. "jutsu" naming reflect Daoist influence?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/9502/5961)